# How to delete resource entry from resx in C#?

Tags: c#, resources, resx

I know how to retrieve and create resource entries in an .resx file programmatically. I'm using the `ResourceWriter` and the `ResourceReader` for that approach. But now I want to clean up several items in my .resx file, and want to delete them. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [ResXResourceReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) and [ResXResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.aspx) classes.

Read your resx using the reader and feed it into the writer, omitting the entries you want removed.

Answer (score 0):

In my work I had to develop to remove from a culture file what I had in a standard culture file.

The code is this:

```
private void ResolveConflicts()
        {
            using (var cultura = new ResXResourceReader(CulturaPath))
            using (var culturaCustom = new ResXResourceReader(CulturaCustomPath))
            {
                Resources = (from cc in culturaCustom.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                             where !(from c in cultura.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                                     select new { c.Key, c.Value })
                             .Contains(new { cc.Key, cc.Value })
                             select new Tuple<string, string>(
                                  cc.Key.ToString(),
                                  cc.Value.ToString())).ToList();
            }

            ReWriteCustomFile();
        }

        private void ReWriteCustomFile()
        {
            using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(CulturaCustomPath))
            {
                Resources.ForEach(r => writer.AddResource(r.Item1, r.Item2));

                writer.Generate();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

With this code, it is recorded in the custom culture only what is different from the default.

I hope it helps, thanks!